# How avoid the certificate validation in spring-boot-admin?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

In what way can I avoid certificate validation in spring-boot-admin?

Link error image:
https://ibb.co/fkZu8y

I configure the RestTemplate for avoid the certificate in a class, but I do not know how to send it, I guess it must be in the client, the spring-boot-admin-starter-client works automatically.

This is the code for avoid the certificate validation.

```
public class SSLUtil {

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

Application.properties

spring.application.name=Admin-Application

server.port=1111

security.user.name=admin

security.user.password=admin123

```
@Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // Page with login form is served as /login.html and does a POST on
            // /login
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
            // The UI does a POST on /logout on logout
            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
            // The ui currently doesn't support csrf
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

                    // Requests for the login page and the static assets are
                    // allowed
                    // http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**").permitAll();
            // ... and any other request needs to be authorized
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

            // Enable so that the clients can authenticate via HTTP basic for
            // registering
            http.httpBasic();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Spring Boot Admin 2.1.3 together with Eureka.

It seems SBA has moved from RestTemplate to WebClient. So I create a WebClient which has a SSLContext with a trust manager set to `InsecureTrustManagerFactory`, that trusts everything. Then I use this webclient and instantiate SBA's InstanceWebClient. Not sure if there is an easier approach, but this worked for me.

```java
import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerProperties;
import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.client.HttpHeadersProvider;
import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.client.InstanceExchangeFilterFunction;
import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.client.InstanceWebClient;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.ConnectionObserver;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AdminServerProperties.class)
public class SslConfiguration {

    private final AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties;

    public SslConfiguration(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminServerProperties = adminServerProperties;
    }


    @Bean
    public InstanceWebClient instanceWebClient(HttpHeadersProvider httpHeadersProvider,
                                        ObjectProvider<List<InstanceExchangeFilterFunction>> filtersProvider) throws SSLException {
        List<InstanceExchangeFilterFunction> additionalFilters = filtersProvider.getIfAvailable(Collections::emptyList);
        return InstanceWebClient.builder()
                .defaultRetries(adminServerProperties.getMonitor().getDefaultRetries())
                .retries(adminServerProperties.getMonitor().getRetries())
                .httpHeadersProvider(httpHeadersProvider)
                .webClient(getWebClient())
                .filters(filters -> filters.addAll(additionalFilters))
                .build();
    }

    private WebClient getWebClient() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .compress(true)
                .secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext))
                .tcpConfiguration(tcp -> tcp.bootstrap(bootstrap -> bootstrap.option(
                        ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                        (int) adminServerProperties.getMonitor().getConnectTimeout().toMillis()
                )).observe((connection, newState) -> {
                    if (ConnectionObserver.State.CONNECTED.equals(newState)) {
                        connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(adminServerProperties.getMonitor().getReadTimeout().toMillis(),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        ));
                    }
                }));
        ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(reactorClientHttpConnector).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @crea1 I need to also override SBA's instance webclient to by pass ssl validation as I'm having a tough time connecting to clients on ssl.  However the code you posted doesn't work for SBA server Version 2.6.2.  Any chance you can post an update?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ustad seems to change a lot (why I posted the version in original answer). Unfortunately I don't work with SBA anymore so I don't have any updates to share.

Comment: Thanks for the response @crea1 I actually found a solution at least for the admin server side connecting back to the clients which is right from their documentation (SBA Admin version 2.6.2): https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_using_mutual_tls
For the client side, I'm using a custom rest template but the SBA client doesn't seem to be picking it up even though I see that the SBA client code is using the BlockingRegistrationClient i.e) RestTemplate

Answer (score 1):

To disable the SBA Admin server from validating SSL certs from the clients it tries to connect to, you can use the following:
For SBA version 2.6.2 it is more or less outlined right from their documentation: https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_using_mutual_tls

Here is the complete configuration overriding bean:

```
package com.markham.mkmappadmin.config;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;

import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

/**
 * Custom http client class which overrides Spring Boot Admin's server default client.<br>
 * The custom client will bypass any SSL Validation by configuring an instance of
 *  {@link InsecureTrustManagerFactory}
 * @author Hanif Rajabali
 * @see <a href="https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_using_mutual_tls">Spring Boot Admin 2.6.2 Using Mutual TLS</a>
 */
@Configuration
public class CustomHttpClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpConnector customHttpClient() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
              .forClient()
              .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
              .build();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(
            ssl -> ssl.sslContext(sslContext)
        );
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }

}
```

What I still haven't figured out is how to disable it from the SBA client.  I have a custom RestTemplate Config defined below, but the SBA client doesn't seem to be picking it up even though I see that the SBA client code is using the BlockingRegistrationClient i.e) RestTemplate

```
package com.markham.mkmemailerws.config;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

/**
 * Need to explicitly build Spring Boot's auto configured
 * {@link #restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder)}
 *
 * @author Hanif Rajabali
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

//   @Bean
//   public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
//      return restTemplateBuilder.build();
//   }


    /**
     * The following will bypass ssl validation altogether. Not ideal.
     */
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory customRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        customRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        return builder.requestFactory(() -> customRequestFactory).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
Above code will disable csrf token. Below is my code for OAuth where I disabled csrf to reduce complexity.

```
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

                        .antMatchers("/api/**", "/dashboard", "/welcome","/about").authenticated().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();

            }
```

Comment: In my SecurityConfig class I already disable the csrf, the error in the spring-boot-admin is the same :(